# Get highest high of bullish divergence in Pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm fairly inexperienced with Pine script, and would really appreciate any/all help with this request. I'm trying to retrieve the HIGHEST HIGH that is formed in a bullish divergence (price makes lower low, indicator makes higher low). Is there a way to capture only those candles that form the divergence, and grab the highest high from within those candles?

Here's the divergence code that I'm working with... Thank you in advance.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Divergence Indicator (any oscillator)', format=format.price, overlay=true, timeframe='')

overlay_main = input(false, title='Plot on price (rather than on indicator)')
osc = input(ohlc4, title='Indicator')
lbR = input(title='Pivot Lookback Right', defval=5)
lbL = input(title='Pivot Lookback Left', defval=5)
rangeUpper = input(title='Max of Lookback Range', defval=60)
rangeLower = input(title='Min of Lookback Range', defval=5)
plotBull = input(title='Plot Bullish', defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input(title='Plot Hidden Bullish', defval=false)
plotBear = input(title='Plot Bearish', defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input(title='Plot Hidden Bearish', defval=false)
delay_plot_til_closed = input(title='Delay plot until candle is closed (don\'t repaint)', defval=false)
bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.new(color.green, 80)
hiddenBearColor = color.new(color.red, 80)
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)

repaint = not delay_plot_til_closed or barstate.ishistory or barstate.isconfirmed

plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish
// Osc: Higher Low

oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low

priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)
bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound and repaint

plot(plFound ? overlay_main ? low[lbR] : osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish', linewidth=2, color=bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor, transp=0)

plotshape(bullCond ? overlay_main ? low[lbR] : osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish Label', text=' Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.new(bullColor, 0), textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))
```

I've tried grabbing codes from similar questions on this site, but I seem to only have found solutions that related to grabbing candles with defined time sessions, and not a "session" marked by the created of a divergence. Could really use some expert advice over here...